# Sudden SocketTimeoutException during Axis2 request

Tags: java, sockets, httpclient, apache-axis

So I'm having a web application (inside tomcat), which uses an Axis2 web service from an external provider. I've generated the code of my web service client according to the WSDL of the provider.

The code was working correctly for at least 6 month now. 6 days ago it stopped working and I got a SocketTimeoutException. The test server wasn't touched for at least a month, so I can rule out changes to the Java binaries or settings in the server.

Here's the juicy part of my stacktrace:

```
[2012-12-12 13:33:15.718 MEZ]: org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: Read timed out
[2012-12-12 13:33:15.718 MEZ]:  at org.apache.axis2.AxisFault.makeFault(AxisFault.java:430)
[2012-12-12 13:33:15.718 MEZ]:  at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPSender.sendViaPost(HTTPSender.java:193)
[2012-12-12 13:33:15.718 MEZ]:  at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPSender.send(HTTPSender.java:75)
[2012-12-12 13:33:15.718 MEZ]:  at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.CommonsHTTPTransportSender.writeMessageWithCommons(CommonsHTTPTransportSender.java:389)
[2012-12-12 13:33:15.718 MEZ]:  at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.CommonsHTTPTransportSender.invoke(CommonsHTTPTransportSender.java:222)
[2012-12-12 13:33:15.718 MEZ]:  at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.send(AxisEngine.java:435)
[2012-12-12 13:33:15.734 MEZ]:  at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.send(OutInAxisOperation.java:402)
[2012-12-12 13:33:15.734 MEZ]:  at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.executeImpl(OutInAxisOperation.java:229)
[2012-12-12 13:33:15.734 MEZ]:  at org.apache.axis2.client.OperationClient.execute(OperationClient.java:165)
[2012-12-12 13:33:15.734 MEZ]:  at my.generated.webservice.client.Quoting_ServiceStub.getQuotesByRequest(Quoting_ServiceStub.java:4215)
...
[2012-12-12 13:33:15.781 MEZ]: Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
[2012-12-12 13:33:15.781 MEZ]:  at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
[2012-12-12 13:33:15.781 MEZ]:  at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:129)
[2012-12-12 13:33:15.781 MEZ]:  at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:218)
[2012-12-12 13:33:15.781 MEZ]:  at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:237)
[2012-12-12 13:33:15.796 MEZ]:  at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpParser.readRawLine(HttpParser.java:78)
[2012-12-12 13:33:15.796 MEZ]:  at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpParser.readLine(HttpParser.java:106)
[2012-12-12 13:33:15.796 MEZ]:  at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpConnection.readLine(HttpConnection.java:1116)
```

This happens on all test and production systems (Windows and Linux).
For communication I'm using HttpClient 3.1 (Apache commons) and already restarted the application and the machines without success.

Now here's the weird thing: I debugged my web service client and was able to send the request XML to the web service server with SoapUI (on Windows) and curl (on Linux) and got a response (reasonable quick within 1,5 seconds). So it's no DNS, firewall or permission problem either.

I appreciate any ideas how to solve this issue.

Comment: one of your library method is setting the socket timeout: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html#setSoTimeout%28int%29

Comment: It certainly isn't a DNS or firewall or permission problem. It's a read timeout. Either you've reconfigured your client or your server has got slower, for example because its load has increased. I suggest you increase the timeout.